# Installing emacs plugins on windows

Tags: windows, emacs, nxhtml

I already looked through other topics, but I still couldn't find a solution. I'm trying to install "nxhtml" plugin for Emacs in windows 7. I already setup my "HOME" environment variable as "C:\". So, my .emacs.d folder is there, and I put the nxhtml in there and added the following line to my "_emacs.d" file, as the readme says:

(load "C:\.emacs.d\nxhtml\autostart.el")

But it doesn't load.

I also tried putting:
(add-to-list 'load-path "C:\.emacs.d\nxhtml")

(load "autostart.el")

But to no avail... can anyone shed some light here? tnx.

Comment: Why on earth would you set `HOME` to `C:\ ` ? (Doesn't Windows 7 have `C:\Users\(username)` for this?) And if you mean that you configured that for Windows' own environment (as opposed to Cygwin or similar), then I think you're asking for problems.

Comment: ...unless Windows has no `HOME` environment variable by default? (But even if that's the case, this doesn't seem like a good idea.)

Answer (score 1):

`\` is special in the (double-quote) read syntax for strings, as certain characters take on a new meaning when prefixed by a backslash (e.g. `\n` is a newline, `\t` is a tab, and `\"` is a double-quote character). When the following character does not have any special meaning in conjunction with the backslash, that character is used verbatim, and the backslash is ignored.

`"C:\.emacs.d\nxhtml\autostart.el"` is actually the string:

```
C:.emacs.d
xhtml^Gutostart.el
```

To include a `\` in the string you need to write `\\`

However, although it will understand the backslashes, Emacs is nowadays consistent across all platforms in allowing `/` as a directory separator<sup>1</sup>; so just do that instead.

<sup>1</sup> and the obsolete `directory-sep-char` variable has been removed entirely.

Comment: Hi phils, yes, I'm aware of double backslash, and I already tried that but to no avail. Also tried with forward slashes and didn't work. In my emacs file I changed my default directory only using normal backslashes and it works normally.

Answer (score 1):

A number of points here:

Firstly, _emacs.d is not a default file name for your init file, ie emacs will not load it automatically.  Try ~/.emacs.d/init.el, or ~/.emacs instead.

Secondly, Windows 7 has a feature where it prevents programs from writing to certain system directories, but for backwards compatibility for the many old programs that do this, rather than causing them to fail, it silently redirects the write elsewhere, in an application specific directory. C:\ is one of those directories, so setting your HOME to point there is asking for trouble.

Thirdly, see the other response about backslash being an escape character in Lisp strings.

Comment: XVirtusX: You should review `C-h i g` `(emacs) Windows HOME` `RET`

Comment: Hi Phils... yes the _emacs.d is a acceptable emacs init file on Windows, because u can't create a file beginning with a dot on Explorer. I've also read somewhere a recomendation to set the HOME environment variable (and no, there is not a default one on Windows) if you want to change your default directory (my case). Anyways, problem is, I've made some changes already to emacs and it is working fine. So I guess it is not a problem with references to files or environment variables... what else should I try?!

Comment: Use the `*scratch*` buffer to check the results of the code. Evaluate `(file-exists-p "C:/.emacs.d/nxhtml/autostart.el")` to make sure it returns `t`, and then `(load "C:/.emacs.d/nxhtml/autostart.el")` to check that it will load. `C-j` after a closing paren will eval-and-print in `*scratch*`.

Comment: XVirtusX, it was me, not phils that pointed out that _emacs.d is not recognized as a name of the init file.  As a special case on Windows, for people who insist on creating an empty file using Explorer, rather than just editing the file in Emacs, _emacs is recognized in addition to .emacs, but this does not apply to the .emacs.d directory, nor to any file by that name.  I suggest you follow phils's advise to read the manual section on handling of HOME on Windows to better understand things.